# What does first argument to `type` do?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Some code.

```
In [1]: A = type('B', (), {})

In [2]: a = A()

In [3]: b = B()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/shabda/<ipython console> in <module>()

NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

What does first argument to `type` doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's setting the `__name__` property of the created class.

When you say:

```
class B(object):
```

two things happen with that 'B':

- The name 'B' is assigned the class. This is just like if you'd said "`B = ...`".
- The `__name__` property of the class is set to 'B'.

When you invoke the type constructor manually only the latter half is done. If you don't assign the result to 'B' then B will remain set (or unset) as it was before.

Note that a similar result could be obtained by saying:

```
class B(object):
    pass
A = B
del B
```

Now A refers to a class that calls itself 'B', and B doesn't refer to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a new class with the name `B`:

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Nov 19 2009, 22:14:20)
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type('B', (), {})
<class '__main__.B'>
```

See the second form of `type` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type) for more information.

When you assign the result of calling `type` to a variable, you're just giving the class `B` another name.  It's equivalent to doing

```
>>> class B(object):
...     pass
...
>>> A = B
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
```

Answer (score 0):

'B' is just a string which is the name of A
One place it is used is for the default `__repr__` of classes and their objects

```
>>> A=type('B', (), {})
>>> A
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> a=A()
>>> a
<__main__.B object at 0xb7cf88ec>
```

The usual way to create a class has no way to explicitly set the `__name__` attribute.
In this case it is implicitly set by the class constructor

```
>>> class A:pass
... 
>>> A
<class __main__.A at 0xb7cf280c>
```

But there is nothing stopping you from changing the name afterward

```
>>> A.__name__
'A'
>>> A.__name__='B'
>>> A
<class __main__.B at 0xb7cf280c>
>>>
```